# Polly FallbackPolicy with Refit and HttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, fallback, polly, refit, httpclientfactory

I use the HttpClientFactory together with Refit to make API calls. I want to use Polly for Retry, Circuit Breaker and Fallback, and while it's easy to set up Retry and Circuit Breaker, I struggle with Fallback, as it can only return a fallback value of type `HttpResponseMessage`, but what is being returned is a `Refit.ApiResponse`. I tried returning a dummy `HttpResponseMessage`, but then Refit breaks as it expects certain things to be present, e.g. the `HttpRequestMessage`.

Has anyone successfully returned a custom object as a fallback value when using `HttpClientFactory` with Refit?

This is the initial setup with Retry:

```
PolicyBuilder<HttpResponseMessage>? policyBuilder = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .Handle<Exception>();

IEnumerable<TimeSpan>? retryDelays = Backoff.DecorrelatedJitterBackoffV2(medianFirstRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), retryCount: 5, fastFirst:true);
AsyncRetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>? retryPolicy = policyBuilder.WaitAndRetryAsync(retryDelays, (exception, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Exception occurred while called Account Service. Retry policy in effect | Retry Attempt: {retryCount} | WaitSeconds: {timeSpan.TotalSeconds}. Exception: {exception.Exception.Message}");
});
```

This is the circuit breaker:

```
AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>? circuitBreakerPolicy = policyBuilder
    .CircuitBreakerAsync(breakCircuitAfterErrors, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(keepCircuitBreakForMinutes),
        (exception, timespan, context) =>
        {
            // OnBreak, i.e. when circuit state changes to open
            Debug.WriteLine(
                $"Account Service circuit breaker policy in effect | State changed to Open (blocked). It will remain open for {keepCircuitBreakForMinutes} minutes");
        },
        (context) =>
        {
            // OnReset, i.e. when circuit state changes to closed
            Debug.WriteLine("Account Service circuit breaker policy in effect | State changed to Closed (normal).");
        });
```

This is the fallback with `HttpResponseMessage`, which breaks Refit:

```
AsyncFallbackPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> fallbackPolicyForCircuitBreaker = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .Handle<BrokenCircuitException>()
    .FallbackAsync((cancellationToken) =>
    {
        // In our case we return a null response.
        Debug.WriteLine($"The Circuit is Open (blocked). A fallback null value is returned. Try again later.");

        return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
    });
```

And here I add the policy handlers to the client:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("AccountService")
    .AddPolicyHandler(fallbackPolicyForCircuitBreaker)
    .AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy)
    .AddPolicyHandler(circuitBreakerPolicy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FallbackAsync` has [several overloads](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/2f84eab6b5087935d66a5c6e4bd5ec230da26c65/src/Polly/Fallback/AsyncFallbackSyntax.cs#L17). One of them looks like this:

```cs
public static AsyncFallbackPolicy<TResult> FallbackAsync<TResult>(
    this PolicyBuilder<TResult> policyBuilder, 
    Func<DelegateResult<TResult>, Context, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> fallbackAction, 
    Func<DelegateResult<TResult>, Context, Task> onFallbackAsync)
```

This means in case of `fallbackAction` you can access the faulted `HttpResponseMessage` via your `DelegateResult`.

```
.FallbackAsync(
  fallbackAction:(dr, ctx, ct) => Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(dr.Result.StatusCode)),
  onFallbackAsync:(dr, ctx) => Task.CompletedTask))
```

But please bear in mind that `dr.Result` is only present if there was no exception. Otherwise `.Result` will be `null` and `.Exception` will contain the thrown exception.

---

If you need to access the request object then you can do that via closure. The `AddPolicyHandler` has the [following overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions-addpolicyhandler(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-ihttpclientbuilder-system-func((system-net-http-httprequestmessage-polly-iasyncpolicy((system-net-http-httpresponsemessage)))))):

```
public static IHttpClientBuilder AddPolicyHandler (
   this IHttpClientBuilder builder, 
   Func<HttpRequestMessage,IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>> policySelector);

public static IHttpClientBuilder AddPolicyHandler (
   this IHttpClientBuilder builder, 
   Func<IServiceProvider,HttpRequestMessage,IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>> policySelector);
```

So, during your registration you can do the following:

```
.AddPolicyHandler(req => Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .Handle<BrokenCircuitException>()
    .FallbackAsync((...) =>
    {
       return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { RequestMessage = req });
    }, ...));
```